# How can I add the domain to either the path or filename used to save a fullpage screenshot taken in Firefox or another browser?

Tags: firefox, browser, screenshot

I take a lot of fullpage screenshots using the developer toolbar in Firefox.  By default, they are saved to

```
~/Downloads/Screen Shot YYYY-MM-DD at HH:MM:SS-fullpage.png
```

Since the screenshots are images, they aren't text-searchable, and I would like them to be automatically organized by the domain of the webpage.

Either like

```
~/Downloads/Screen Shot amazon YYYY-MM-DD at HH:MM:SS-fullpage.png
~/Downloads/Screen Shot ebay YYYY-MM-DD at HH:MM:SS-fullpage.png
```

Or like

```
~/Downloads/amazon/Screen Shot YYYY-MM-DD at HH:MM:SS-fullpage.png
~/Downloads/ebay/Screen Shot YYYY-MM-DD at HH:MM:SS-fullpage.png
```

I've explored <s>two</s> four solutions:

1. **Alias the GCLI screenshot command with a parameter in the filename.**  I thought aliasing would definitely be supported, but it turns out the feature request was abandoned years ago [here](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=760819) and [here](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=731606).
2. **Turn on [this option](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Preferences/Preference_reference/browser.download.lastDir.savePerSite) for Firefox to remember last-used save locations per-domain.**  This gets closer assuming it works as advertised, but still requires a manual step to set the location for each new domain, by arbitrarily saving a file from the domain to the desired target location.

   *Update*:  This does not work as advertised.  Saving arbitrary content from a domain to a target directory does update the `browser.download.lastDir` preference to that directory, but subsequent screenshots of pages from that domain are still saved to the `browser.download.dir` preference setting.
   *Update 2*: This is because this preference setting [only controls the file picker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Preferences/Preference_reference/browser.download.lastDir.savePerSite).
3. **Temporarily override the `browser.download.dir` preference setting programmatically by modifying a [user.js](http://kb.mozillazine.org/User.js_file) file.**  The problem with this is that `user.js` is only loaded at startup.  There isn't a way to trigger reloading it without restarting the whole browser.
4. **Modify the filename template string used for screen shots created by the operating system.  [Eric Meyer says](https://meyerweb.com/eric/thoughts/2018/08/24/firefoxs-screenshot-command-2018/) that Firefox "uses the pattern of your OS screen capture naming."**  But it does not.  Firefox uses a pattern hard-coded in [screenshot.properties](https://searchfox.org/mozilla-central/source/devtools/shared/locales/en-US/screenshot.properties#88) which is only coincidentally the same template pattern as Mac OS default.

---

Bonus points if there is also a way for screenshots taken using Command-Shift-4 in OS X to be saved the same way.  But being able to take a full-page (scrolling) screenshot of a rendered webpage is more important to me.  I am open to using a different browser if aliasing CLI commands is supported.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know.  Another reason to *never update software*.  I'll edit the question, because I think screenshots can still be taken by clicking on some button somewhere, although that's not how I use it.

Comment: ["is unmaintained for some time now, many commands are broken"](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?format=default&id=1429421) – probably not a state where you want to stop updating.

Comment: They are nixing it, not fixing it.  So it's not as if I would a get a version that is maintained instead of unmaintained by updating.  They also acknowledge that they are leaving users without a way to take full-page screenshots [here](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1429421#c21) and [here](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1429421#c26)

Comment: Thanks @dsstorefile1.  I continued to use GCLI in ESR releases until today.  Apparently it was removed with the update to Firefox 68.0.1esr.  So with this `:screenshot` command in Web Console, can I pass any kind of non-literal to the `--filename` option?  I tried JavaScript, it seems not interpreted.  Even `~` is not expanded to the user home directory.